# 'case' inside of where clause

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following class method, and was wondering if there is an prettier (more ruby-ist) way of going about this.

```
def self.of_users_that(type)
  case type 
  when "registered"
    type = 1
  when "apologized"
    type = 2
  end
  Subscription.where(:regoption_id => type)
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually declare a constant inside the model for these kinds of constants. So same answer as Sergio, but using the constant

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  USER_TYPES = { 'registered' => 1, 'apologized' => 2 }

  def self.of_users_that(type)
    where(regoption_id: USER_TYPES[type])
  end
end
```

or just use scopes

```
scope :registered, where(regoption_id: 1)
scope :apologized, where(regoption_id: 2)
```

or combination

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  USER_TYPES = { 'registered' => 1, 'apologized' => 2 }

  scope :registered, where(regoption_id: USER_TYPES['registered'])
  scope :apologized, where(regoption_id: USER_TYPES['apologized'])
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It's considered bad taste (a code smell) to redefine variables like that (transform it from string to integer).

Here's a cleaner version of your code:

```
def self.of_users_that(type)
  map = {'registered' => 1, 
         'apologized' => 2}
  Subscription.where(:regoption_id => map[type])
end
```

Comment: Reusing variables with different values is a terrible practice, which is sad because it's extremely common (and so easy to fix...).